# How to force a 404 on wordPress mu-plugins

Tags: wordpress

I need to force a 404 on some conditions.
I tried this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/how-to-force-a-404-on-wordpress

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set_404();
status_header(404);
```

It doesnt work because mu-plugins is very early.

How to force 404 and show default wordpress 404 page. If its possible in wordpress way.